# disable multiple selection in UniSharp package laravel

Tags: laravel, multi-select, unisharp-file-manager

How disable multiple selection in UniSharp package laravel?
see image i need select just one image!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I solved It,
In View put,

`window.open(route_prefix + '?type=' + options.type+'?&multiple=false' || 'file', 'FileManager', 'width=900,height=600');`

instead of

`window.open(route_prefix + '?type=' + options.type|| 'file', 'FileManager', 'width=900,height=600');`

and open vendor\unisharp\laravel-filemanager\public\js\script.js file

update these lines:

```
var myParam = location.search.split('multiple=')[1];//new
//alert(myParam);//new
if(myParam == 'false'){ //new
  multi_selection_enabled = multi_selection_enabled;//
}else{
    multi_selection_enabled = !multi_selection_enabled;//here
}
```

instead of:

`multi_selection_enabled = !multi_selection_enabled;`